# How do I use previous user input and put it into another user input statement?

Tags: string, matlab, input, string-formatting, user-input

```
a = input('What is the name of the exoplanet? ','s');

mass = input('What is the mass of %s (kg)? ', a)

radius = input('What is the estimated radius of %s (km)? ', a)

masssp = input('What is the mass of the specimen (kg) ')

newton = (mass * radius)/masssp

fprintf('On %s , it would weight approxomately %d Newtons ', s, newton)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need sprintf for your text

```
a = input('What is the name of the exoplanet? ','s');
mass   = str2num(input(sprintf('What is the mass of %s (kg)?', a),'s'));
radius = str2num(input(sprintf('What is the estimated radius of %s (km)?', a),'s')) ;
```

and later convert your string to a number, otherwise you can't do calculations with it...